# converting milliseconds to nearest minute in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, momentjs

Using javascript/jquery how can you convert from an integer duration in milliseconds to the nearest minute?

For example:
900000 milliseconds should equal 15 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
var millisecondVal = 900000;
var minuteVal = millisecondVal / 60000;
alert(minuteVal);
minuteVal = Math.round(minuteVal);
alert(millisecondVal + "miliseconds value to the nearest minute:" + minuteVal);
```

Comment: Don't you need to round "to the nearest minute"?

Answer (score 0):

Being 1 minute equal to 60000 milliseconds, you can simply use something like `Math.round(your_elapsed_time/60000)`.
In other terms: first of all divide by 1000 to find the number of seconds, secondly divide by 60 to find the number of minutes, finally round it to the nearest number.